# If $c > a > 0$ and $a − b + c = 0$, find the largest root of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $c > a > 0$ and $a − b + c = 0$, find the largest root of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.

Edit: The key says that the larger root is $-a-b+c$. Is there something wrong with the key?

Comment: Next time, consider adding more tags such as ''algebra-precalculus'', ''polynomials' 'or ''roots''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have: $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
When you put $x=-1$, you get: $$a-b+c=0$$
Roots are: $$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Substitute $b=a+c$ in it: $$\frac{-(a+c)\pm\sqrt{(a+c)^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$=\frac{-(a+c)\pm\sqrt{(a-c)^2}}{2a}$$
Solving, you get roots as $-\frac ca$ and $-1$, out of which, $-1$ will be greater,
because: $$c>a>0 \implies \frac ca>1$$

Comment: it is something wrong $$\sqrt{(a+c)^2-4ac}=\sqrt{(a-c)^2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using that $$b=a+c$$ and the quadratic formula we get 
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{a+c}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{(a-c)^2}}{2a}$$ since $$a>c$$ we get
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{a+c}{2a}\pm\frac{a-c}{2a}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $a-b+c=0$, $-1$ is a root of $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

It is well-known that the product of the roots of a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $\dfrac ca$, so the other root is $-\dfrac ca$.

Since $c>a>0$, the other root is less than $-1$, hence $-1$ is the largest root.

Answer (score 0):

For a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx +c = 0$ with $a \neq 0$, the roots are $x = \frac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}.$

We are given $b = a+c$. Substituting $b$ for $a+c$ in the expression for the roots yields $$x = \frac{-(a+c) \pm \sqrt{(a-c)^2}}{2a} = \frac{-(a+c) \pm |a-c|}{2a}.$$ We know $c > a \iff a -c < 0$, which implies that $|a-c|= -(a-c) = c-a$. Hence, $$x = \frac{-a-c \pm (c-a)}{2a} \iff x = -1 \ \text{or} \ x = -\frac{c}{a}. $$ So, which one is larger? We can find out by taking the difference of the roots, $-1 - (-\frac{c}{a}) = -1 + \frac{c}{a} = \frac{c-a}{a} > 0$ since $c > a$ and $a > 0$.

Hence, $(-1) - (-\frac{c}{a}) > 0 \iff -1 > -\frac{c}{a}.$ I.e. $-1$ is the larger root.